# The Suggested Edit quota is too low

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

Recently I have become able to start doing First Post reviews, but while I am doing so, I have to edit a lot of posts that are of low quality.

However, when I started my 6th edit, I repeatedly click on the "Edit" button and nothing happened. Only going back to the question and clicking the "Edit" button revealed that I had reached the edit quota ("too many pending edit suggestions").

Why are edit suggestions limited to 5, rather than, say, 10? Sometimes I feel a desperate need to edit a very low quality post, but I am not able to do so because of this restriction.

Comment: Maybe we should just be reviewing more quickly...

Comment: Yes, but then I know that each person only has 20 votes. Some people will decide to skip my suggested edits, causing the review procedure run slowly... It will be better if edit suggestions can expand to 10, that way even though approval is slow, but at least more edits can be carried out.

Comment: [Post on Meta Stack Exchange about why suggested edits should be limited](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210416/rate-limit-suggested-edits) for context. Thanks for reviewing posts and suggesting edits!

Comment: @Cynplytholowazy Please don't edit off-topic questions like [this one](https://askubuntu.com/q/956962/167850)

Comment: @Pilot6 Er, well, but at least it is possible to migrate this question to Unix & Linux Stack Exchange, isn't it? Making this question looks better and flagging it as off-topic is the only thing I can do.

Comment: It makes no sense to make it better, especially by adding the picture. If you see an off-topic question, just flag it as off-topic. It saves time of reviewers and allows you to do more useful edits..

Comment: Now, yes, I made a couple of edits to off-topic questions. But only when I am not doing reviews. When I am doing reviews I will ignore the format, just downvote and flag it. I see no point not to do such edit when there is good enough quota for me.

Comment: Also, What I am talking about is the Edit quota *during review*. We may run out of quota when reviewing, but not during casual walkthrough in Ask Ubuntu. (Maybe we can add extra quota for reviewing?)

Comment: I somewhat disagree with Pilot6. I edit off-topic questions, especially  if they are migrateable, but I try to avoid doing it if the post is already [on hold] and not yet [closed] (status changes after a few days) because editing sends the post to the reopen queue, wasting the time of 3 reviewers. I also try not to edit posts (like off topic questions) that are likely to be deleted on sites where I don't have edit privileges, as people have to review my edit.

Comment: It's also a difference though if you edit a post that will likely get closed as off-topic with *more* or *less* than 2000 reputation points. That is the limit above which you can edit directly without needing review. There is nothing bad about a direct edit to an open question, as it does not generate any review items that need manual human work.

Comment: I raised the problem of your not getting an error message on the review page on:  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301083/hitting-the-suggested-edit-limit-in-a-review-queue-is-failing-silently